# colcon build error for rclpy - not providing Findrcl_logging_interface.cmake

Tags: ros2

I have a Python program that requires the rclpy library. When I try to run the program I get a module not found error. I found a [git repo](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy) that outlines the process. I replaced "rolling" with "foxy" to match the version of ros2 that I have installed. During the step for `colcon build --symlink-install`, the following error is

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findrcl_logging_interface.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
  by "rcl_logging_interface", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "rcl_logging_interface" with any of the following names:

    rcl_logging_interfaceConfig.cmake
    rcl_logging_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rcl_logging_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "rcl_logging_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "rcl_logging_interface" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I'm very new to ros and I don't know how to resolve this issue. What information can I provide to help with diagnostics?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

ROS2: Roxy

Answer (score 0):

1. First things first, please make sure you install ROS2 with the guide provided at https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation.html.
2. If installation is fine, then check if you sourced the ROS2 base environment with

> source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash

3. If the error still persists, then clone https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging within src of your workspace,and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding rcl_logging_noop rclpy
```

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.

```
Starting >>> rcl_logging_interface
--- stderr: rcl_logging_interface                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (ament_export_targets):
  Unknown CMake command "ament_export_targets".
```

---

Failed   <<< rcl_logging_interface [4.60s, exited with code 1]

```
Summary: 0 packages finished [6.47s]
  1 package failed: rcl_logging_interface
  1 package had stderr output: rcl_logging_interface
  3 packages not processed
```

I have the same issue. @mct_fellow's recommendation didnt work